# How can I repeat a function in python3 without using a while loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, repeat

I have a function in python three that needs to be run constantly and check some variables. At the moment I have a while loop and everything runned smooth, until I wanted to use a pyqt widget and that ended up in a disaster.

I've found the twisted.internet module over an other thread in stackoverflow, but I can't get it to run over python3.

is there an other module that allows me to repeat a certain function to run every 0.01 sec in python3 without idling my code?

Comment: It's very likely not the `while` loop that was the problem.  What is it you were doing?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html

Comment: If you want to run a function repeatedly on a set interval without blocking your program, schedule an event (with pyqt's equivalent of Tkinter's `after()`, whatever that is).

Comment: I am truing to run a function that has a while loop that runs for ever ( and this what it has to be doing), and a creation of window with a text box inside it. If I comment the while loop the window pops up but my function doesn't work, while it is fundamental for it. If I uncomment the while loop my function works perfect but the window never pops up. So my thought was to run some kind of code that repeats this function without using an endless loop. repeat it lets say every 0.01 seconds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using pyqt that means there's a running event loop (which your while loop would block) - you can ask that to schedule a function call after a certain amount of time without needing to loop yourself.

Using a [QTimer](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtimer.html) sounds like what you need. [This](http://ralsina.me/weblog/posts/BB974.html) is a bit of a simpler example of using one.

From that second link:

```
timer = QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(your_function)
timer.start(100)
```

That will do what you want, as long as the QTimer stays alive (if it gets garbage collected it will stop).

Comment: Thanks. so by using QTimer.start (write_msg(), int 100) would run my write_msg() function every 100mils. Right ? Am I missing something here?